# Delete blank pages of a MS Word document with powershell script

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I'm trying to create a script that deletes all of the blank pages of the MS Word documents located in a working directory. The thing is that we don't know which pages are blank, so I need to iterate through all the pages to see which ones are blank. Each page has a header and a footer (even the blank ones).

I've tried to write the code myself, but I have no experience with PowerShell and couldn't find any help on the Internet :( This is the incomplete 'code' (hehehe) I've written.

If you could please help me I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

````
# Locate current working directory and filter .doc files
$docs = GetChildrem -Path $scriptrPath -Recurse -Include *.docx
# Navigate through each word file in the working directory
foreach ($doc in $docs){
# Open the word file
    $wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $wd.Visible = $false
    $docu = $wd.Documents.Open($f.FullName)
# Scroll through pages of a particular word file
    $pages = $wd.ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic]::wdStatisticPages)
    $pages
    for ($i = 1; $i = $pages ){
# Check if the page is blank
        if ($docu.

# Delete blank page


# Update Table of Contents


# Save word file
$doc.SaveAs($scriptrPath + $f,$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
$word.Quit()

```
````

Comment: You have to use the MSOffice Object Model to open Word and use that COM to do what you need.  You only need to open Word once, then open the doc, do your work and close doc. You can get a template of the code Word will use by opening up Word, using the macro recorder, and click-thru the UI to delete one or all pages using Word as normal. [Save that VBA code](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vba+%27delete+blank+page+Micrsoft+Word%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=vba+%27delete+blank+page+micrsoft+word%27&sc=0-37&sk=&cvid=B74A1084233A473B8DEEB4C3554DA763) and tweak as needed in your script.

Comment: As for this... [ I have no experience with PowerShell], then you really should get some training on PowerShell in general first. Just on Youtube and search for Beginning PowerShell and then PowerShell MSWord.

Comment: A potential issue will be with documents that use even and odd headers and footers. Those documents can have automatically-created undeleteable blank pages that ensure odd pages always are on the right of a 2-page spread.